# Get the desired octet of an IP v.4

Tags: vb.net

How do I get the last octet of an IP v.4 address?

Example: `192.168.1.130`

I want to get `130` which is the last octet of the given IP v.4 address.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Working Code:

```
IPAddress.Parse(host).GetAddressBytes(3)
```

Where `3` in `GetAddressBytes(3)` is the `octet`, so if you have `192.168.1.130` as an example IP v.4 address, if you changed `3` to

`0` - `192`

`1` - `168`

`2` - `1`

`3` - `130`

Comment: That was quite the fast answer