# How to get the desired octet in an IP address that includes port number?

Tags: vb.net, parsing, ip-address, ipv4, port-number

If I have this kind of IP address `192.168.110.128` the way to get the desired octet is already answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32217583/get-the-desired-octet-of-an-ip-v-4), but it's not applicable to the IP that includes port number like this `192.168.110.128:60423`.

Comment: Convert to string and parse...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't parse this into an IPAddress object as port is not part of the IP address. It belongs to TCP/UDP.

Instead you will have to parse it into a URI and then get the host value of that, parse that into an IPAddress and there you go:

```
    Dim address As String = "192.168.110.128:60423"
    Dim ip = IPAddress.Parse(New Uri("http://" & address).Host)
    Debug.WriteLine(ip.GetAddressBytes(3))
```

Comment: Thank you so much, very good explanation Sir. I didn't realize that port number belongs to TCP/UDP